# DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, txt

After several successful pipelines witch move .txt files from you Azure fileshare to your Azure SQL-server I am experiencing problems with moving one specific file to an sql-server table. I get the following errorcode:

`ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'chauf_afw.txt' with row number 2: found more columns than expected column count 5.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'`

Azure Data factory sees 5 column on both sink and source side. On both sides(source and sink) I have a schema with 5 columns, the final schematic look likes following.
[schematic picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AYJU.png) The .txt file contains 6 columns when counting the tabs.

The source file is a UTF-8 .txt file with tab separated data nothing special and in the same format as the other successfully imported files.

Regarding the delimiter the file used tabs in notepad++ it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gLlD.png).

I am afraid I am missing something but I can't file the cause the the error code.

Comment: It seems there might be a column delimiter value within the data itself

Comment: The used file looks to me like a normal .txt file. I used Notepad++ to check the file.

Comment: What I mean is lets say my file is delimited with "|" as delimiter . you might have the same "|" value in some data like lets say:     a|"a|b"|c
ideally there are only 3 column but ADF might read it as 4 columns untill you mention quote chars

Comment: @Nandan I have added a some text and a screenshot to my question. I hope this make this more clear.

Comment: In row no  2 of you file may have more than 5 columns that's why you are getting this error can you please share sample data.

Comment: @PratikLad Thank young, I have checked the the source file and found an extra tab behind each row. I have contacted the programmer who made the export.

Comment: You can use data flow to overcome this problem

Comment: @PratikLad, does data flow has the possibility to remove characters from a file? As far as I can see a dataflow only works with tables.